# How to add a box underneath the Post Box in Wordpress admin?

Tags: custom-field, admin

I'm wondering how to add a new box underneath the Post Box (Publish Box) in the admin section of WordPress?  Am hoping to add a few custom field text inputs there.

Comment: Have you seen [Best practices for meta box placement?](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/77224/73) Positioning and registration are explained there.

Comment: That definitely helped me, just needed to change 'normal' to 'side' in the argument section of 'add_meta_box('.  Thanks for sending me in the right direction toscho!